# jquery cycle slide show not fading in IE

Tags: jquery, sifr, jquery-cycle, sifr3

This is crazy Frankenstein collision of jquery cycle, sIFR3 and some other stuff--it works great in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but not IE 7 or 8 (of course).

http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/testimonials/sifr-dual.html

There are two jquery cycle slideshows here set to different rates--one for the sIFR text (no fade) and one with a fade for the photos. I did have everything in one show, but it did weird stuff to the sIFR when the slides faded and out. (Note that I have a small delay set for the sIFR to trigger--sIFR won't load past the first slide without it.)

Any ideas about how to get this freakin' page to work in IE 7&8?? I want the photos to fade in and out, sIFR text can just snap in and out without fading. Thank you!

Comment: It works fine for my part in IE...

Comment: Thanks Alxandr, the photos fade in and out gradually and just don't blink on and off as they're changed? May I ask what OS you're on? I'm not having in luck in XP in either IE 7 or 8...

Comment: What I'm going to try tomorrow is get rid of the background-color in my CSS the slideshow DIV--it's redundant since the parent DIV's color is the same.

Comment: have you found a solution? if no your link is dead. otherwise post a solution for future reference

Comment: Sure, sorry about that, here's the updated test-page: http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/testimonials/

Answer (score 0):

I've found that IE 7&8 have a tough time fading divs that have divs nested inside them.

IE7 seems to work better (just a little) with this arrangement, IE8 just clicks them on with no transition.

Here's my updated and streamlined test page:

http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/testimonials/

**I'm forcing it into IE7 emulation mode and hoping IE9 will be more jQuery fade friendly.**

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

I'll be watching my Google Analytics data over the coming months and when I'm satisfied that enough visitors are using IE9, I'll remove that meta code--I've yet to test this page in IE9, however.

Safari and FF have no trouble with this page in either Windows or Mac (the photos fade, not the text which is sIFR--I'm fine with that). Since this page works well with the non-IE browsers, I'm moving on and not worrying about IE as the page functions with IE, it's just not as nice an experience. I'd still love to know how to make the transition fade in IE, however.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found that the slide items needed width and height set in the CSS, otherwise they did not fade but flash white instead.